# How to call C++ function in LLVM IR?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I am new to LLVM IR, I have a LLVM IR source code and it uses some extern declare functions.
These functions are implemented in a C++ file.

So my question is :

How to call these c++ function in the LLVM IR?

Is it right way to compile the c++ file into LLVM IR, and **link** them together?

Comment: In addition to what @bames53 suggested, you can also compile the C++ to LLVM IR and link them at IR level. Or you can have a C++ program that contains these external functions JIT LLVM IR and let them load it from the process. There's a number of ways to go about it, depends on your exact needs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the llvm IR declarations are ABI compatible with your C++ compiler you should be able to compile the C++ to a native object file, compile the LLVM IR to a native object file, and link them using the native linker